# How to align electrical boxes/plugs?

Tags: electrical, drywall, junction-box

A wall of a second-floor full bath (in TX) has the following outlets.
[image]
[image]
The middle box is for a phone wire! I plan to remove this box. This box is nailed to a 2 by 4 above it that is running between the studs.
There is also a slightly slanted 2 by 4 below the now-removed mini wall vanity/shelf. The shelf is to be placed back.

The double plug on the left is nailed to a stud to its left.
The triple switch is nailed to a stud to its right.
All incoming or outgoing wires are through the bottom of the boxes.
The studs are about 14 inches apart.

The plug and switch are not level with each other. They are off by about 1/2 inch.
Their boxes also are not flush with the drywall, they are inset too much and there is a gap between the face plate of the triple switch and the switches.

I am planning to replace the plug and switches but I want

(a) for them to be flush with the drywall

(b) for the plug and the triple switch to be level

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you ok with opening up the wall around and between the switch set and wall plug?

Comment: @Jack  Yes, but the amount of slack in wires of plug might not be enough to move it to right and have  a 4 gang.

Comment: True, but the only way to find out the safest way is to open up the wall, that way it can be seen if the wires are fed from the top, bottom or both. It also will allow the new box to be added after the others are removed IF the wires allow it. Yes it could be a mighty big "if". At the least they should be able to be set at level with each other, if not slightly closer, if that is preferred.

Comment: @Jack , So you suggest to remove a big rectangle of sheetrock, including all three outlets and a portion of studs to see the wiring, move what can be moved, and reposition, then nails the new sheetrock to the studs.

Comment: Yes that's why the first question. If you are willing to open up the wall, and if needed open it up enough to reroute the existing wires into another box in an appropriate spot or spots, or even if there is an attic is above the bathroom, add a junction box in the attic to run new wires wherever you like to the best positions.

Comment: Removing some sheetrock would also allow removal of the phone outlet box and not need a cover plate.   Also, the OP may need to "split the difference" by moving one box down 1/4" and the other up 1//4" depending upon how the cables are run. In any case, pulling off some sheetrock would simplify the job.

Comment: @Ecnerwal says it all. That would be the way to do it if the cables allowed. If the cables limited your possibilities, it will allow you to add blocks to remount the boxes closer together or farther away from the door, or both, or add another receptacle farther down the wall for convenience. If the receptacle was fed from the bottom, I would lower it a bit if there is a countertop near by. If the pic shown the surrounding areas, I could be more descriptive. I do presume there is a door near the switches.

Comment: @Jack I added the picture showing the work area. The blue J-boxes they sell require quite a bit of clearance to nail in those angled nails. Looks like another reason to lower the boxes. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is that is part of the reason, but there are boxes that will allow screws to be used too. The opening up of the wall, is to see where the give and take is on the wires. The driving force behind it too. is the want to remove the phone box. These look like they are mounted in the old school plastic boxes which are not real plastic, but perhaps bakelite? Now that I see you do have a mirror there, do not cut into that corner to expose that stud, stay away from that mirror to avoid cracking or chipping. Also since you have a sink splash below, make you first cut, above the splash about 4".

Comment: I just realized that the original boxes will be very difficult to remove without removing the wall material. The nailing bracket is MUCH different than the new ones. Typically it is a metal strap that is connected to the box and extends a few inches above and below the box. So even to raise or lower the existing boxes would be impractical. Even for just a 1/4"....

Comment: @Jack  There are junction boxes with four flaps that turn upright behind the drywall when a screw is tightened. So no nailing is done.  I am planning to put such a box, with 4 components. Is that a reasonable idea? Do these screws stay tight over a long time?

Comment: @Jack  An issue came up after I cut the wall. There is a standard 1/2 inch drywall. But on top it there is a 1/8 inch of what appears to be thick joint compound. So what should I do to level the new drywall with the old surface? Put a shimmy behind it on the studs or cover it with a lot of joint compound?

Comment: On the first answer the new plastic boxes have "wings that turn into position when you cut the opening accurately for the box if you want to go that way. I would add the blocking needed to set the box or boxes exactly as I want it and set the drywall.

Comment: About the drywall. whenever I have a lot of mud at the cut I made to make a repair, I scrape off the excess mud, down to or close to the paper layer of the drywall, trying not to damage the paper layer too bad. Do this about 2-3" around the perimeter, where possible, before you set the new drywall. This is why I mentioned in an earlier comment keeping the cut 4" away from the sink splash for this purpose. This will allow the tape over the joint still be below the level of the troweled drywall finish you have. Then ad the new mud over the new drywall to match the thickness and texture you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Turn off the power at the breaker
- Rip the wall open
- Pull out the devices from the boxes and **label** the wires of the devices
- Remove the devices
- Unclamp the cables and pull them back
- Pry off the boxes
- Place new boxes
- Insert and clamp the cables
- Repair the wall
- Replace the devices following the labels applied earlier
- Turn breaker on and verify correct operation
- Install cover plates

Note that a small drywall repair is typically at least as much work, if not more work, than a large drywall repair - A sheet is 4x8 feet, so feel free to go (up to) that large if it simplifies your re-wiring at all.

Comment: All this presumes that there's enough cable in the wall to move the box the desired amount. One box (the outlets, for example) may need to move down to match the height of the other (the switches, for example) if there isn't enough room to move the switches up. Actually, I'd strongly recommend moving the outlet box, not the switch box, simply because there is less electrical work involved and, therefore, easier.

Comment: OP wants **both** boxes to move (out to face of wall) as well as to align them vertically. Given it's a matter of 1/4" per box if both move, it would be very surprising not to have enough wire to manage that; but if need be, a junction box is easily added.

Comment: "Replace the devices following the labels applied earlier" => throw away the receptacle that should be a GFCI, and put new $2 rocker switches while you're at it.

Comment: is it ok to release some of the staples that hold the wires to the studs to make it easier to move the box to the middle of the area between the two studs.

Comment: If you do it without damaging the cables.

Comment: As it turned out our breaker was not labeled properly. So even if it disconnected some power it did not disconnect all of them. Somehow the adjacent BR had to be disconnected too. So on the first step I suggest adding "and test for power at all wires".